# What can I do if my Cannabis plant starts flowering early

Tags: plant-care

I have an Alaskan Thunderfuck that is a little over a month old that started flowering. It has been growing alongside several other plants and nun are in a 12-12 light cycle. The plant is still small and being fed liquid Miricle Grow 12-4-8 for veg. Can I get the plant back into veg. or should I switch to bloom nutrients and let it go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with these American *Cannabis* strains, since I live in Amsterdam (we had different genetic selection here). A small search on Google tells me that your ATF strain contains some *Cannabis ruderalis* genetics next to the usual *sativa*. Now this *ruderalis* is interesting, since it can cause auto flowering. This is a process in which the plants start to flower after 6-8 weeks under each light cycle regime.

Now my guess is that this is causing the early flowering in your ATF plant. There is no way to undo this process, so let it go in bloom now. Trying to get your plant back in vegetative state would give it stress and guaranteed bad harvest.

Comment: That would make perfect sense and explain why she is flowering in 4-5 weeks.